# CSS: Footer that is always under main content but also visible in fixed sidebar

Tags: css

I have a fixed sidebar with three sections: header, content, and footer. The sidebar always takes up the height of the viewport. Below are specifications for how I would like the sidebar to behave, illustrated with a figure.

Let:

- V, H, C and F be the heights of the viewport, header, content, and footer boxes
- Cmin be a minimum value for C
- Hc, Cc, and Fc be the heights of the *contents* of the header, content, and footer boxes (these are constants)

Then the specifications are:

- if V > Hc + Cc + Fc

  - normal flow lays out everything (Fig 1.1)
- if V < Hc + Cc + Fc

  - if V > Hc + Cmin + Fc

    - C decreases, while H and F remain constant (Fig 1.2)
    - content gains a scrollbar
  - if V < Hc + Cmin + Fc

    - C remains at Cmin
    - F begins to be truncated from the bottom of the page (Fig 1.4)
    - F is not visible until the viewport is enlarged again

How can I achieve this?

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox. Something like this:

```css
aside {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section {
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
/* Optional styles */ aside { border: 1px solid; resize: vertical; } header { background: #f9f; } section { background: #ff9; } footer { background: #9ff; }
```

```html
<aside>
  <header>I'm<br />the<br />header</header>
  <section>I'm the content<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem.</section>
  <footer>I'm<br />the<br />footer</footer>
</aside>↑ You can resize the sidebar ↑
```

Comment: Thanks Oriol. Your exact code did not quite accomplish what I was aiming for but your suggestion to use flexbox led me to the correct answer. If you update your answer with the css I have in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/smackesey/pen/Ywoxgd), which achieves the desired result, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @SeanMackesey Isn't your codepen basically the same? You added `flex: 0 0` to make the flex items inflexible, but in my snippet they don't shrink neither because of `min-height: auto`

Comment: Your snippet does not show the behavior in Fig 1.2 and 1.3. When I scroll up on your snippet, the footer immediately begins disappearing-- what should happen is that the content should first begin shrinking until it hits a minimum height, at which point the footer begins to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

`max-height: 100vh;` to the sidebar

```css
html,body { margin:0;}
.sidebar{
  width: 25%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}
header{
  height:100px;
  background: steelblue;
}
section.content{
  height: 500px;
  background: powderblue;
}
footer{
  background : blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <header>header</header>
    <section class="content">content</section>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here's a demo to show if the content section is too small to get the scroll bars. I made the background of the side bar green so it represents a section.

```css
html,body {height:100%; margin:0;}
.sidebar{
  width: 25%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
header{
  height:100px;
  background: steelblue;
}
section.content{
  height: 300px;
  background: powderblue;
}
footer{
  background : blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <header>header</header>
    <section class="content">content</section>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. Your current answer doesn't quite do what I want and I realize my initial question wasn't clear enough, so I updated it.